# Make Split View in Visual Studios 2010 Vertical

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How do you make the "split" view function a vertical split rather than a horizontal split in **Microsoft Visual Studios 2010**? In particular, I want to do this when editing .aspx files.

Note: There are several articles noting how to do this in VS 2008 however VS 2010 seems to be different. Note the picture below, there is no HTML editor and even in the Text Editor there exists no option to split vertical.

[VS 2010 Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AyT8.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just right click the tab and select "New Vertical Tab Group"

Update:

Split view vertically
 - Go to Tools > Options > HTML Designer
 - Check Split views vertically
 - Restart Visual Studio

Comment: Yes I understand how to do that, I am specifically asking for how to do this in **split view** which is where you view the Design and Source view at the same time in the same tab. What you are referring to is viewing two separate tabs at once.

Comment: Sorry about that. I answered too quickly. See my updated answer @StephenLasky

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using VS2019:

I am using Visual Studio community 2019 for WebForm.aspx

Go to Tools > Options > Web Forms Designer
-Tick split view vertically
-Restart Visual Studio

[Click here to view Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpVLn.png)